# Filter with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to make a filter with the `angularJs` **directive** called `ng-repeat` the filter works as follows: 
When you click on the `checkbox` filters in an array the items that have `offers`, I'm using a function to filter, I think there is a better way to do it without so much code.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $document) {

    $scope.items = [
        {
            id: 0,
            description: "Primer Item 1",
            offers: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: "Casa"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            description: "Segundo Item 2"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            description: "Tercer Item 3"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            description: "Cuarto Item 4"
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            description: "Quinto Item 5"
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            description: "Sexto Item 5",
            offers: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Bodega"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            description: "Septimo Item 6"
        },
        {
            id: 7,
            description: "Octavo Item 7"
        },
        {
            id: 8,
            description: "Noveno Item 8"
        },
        {
            id: 9,
            description: "Decimo Item 9"
        }
    ];

    $scope.filterItem = function() {
        if (!$scope.itemOffer){
            $scope.filterOffer = function(item) {
                return item.offers && item.offers.length > 0;
            };
            $scope.itemOffer = true;
        } else {
            $scope.filterOffer = function(item) {
                return item;
            };
            $scope.itemOffer = false;
        }
    };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="propertyOffer" ng-model="propertyOffer" ng-click="filterItem()">Item with offert
        <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: filterOffer track by $index">
            {{ item }}
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-if with the ng-repeat directive to filter items containing offers at will :

**JS CODE**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $document) {
    $scope.offersOnly = false;
    $scope.items = [
        // Your items
    ];
});
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="offersOnly" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false"/>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="!offersOnly">
        {{item}}
    </div>

    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="offersOnly && item.offers">
        {{item}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: some other way to do it without a function? @Joe25

Comment: @TheVicious Sorry for the delay, yes sure, you can use a condition with ng-if like so : <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-if="item.offers">{{item}}</div>

Comment: you can make a complete process with the code I have and what you are going to implement new @Joe25

Comment: I will update the original answer with the full working code in this case

Comment: is not the best answer but it has been useful @Joe25